# Java Spring: What is best way to do a mysql query using an IN clause using JdbcTemplates?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbctemplate

If I have a bunch of stuff in quotes I find myself doing something like:

```
String sql = "SELECT col1, col2, col3 "
           + "FROM my_awesome_table "
           + "WHERE strValue IN (%s)";

sql = String.format(sql, COMMA_JOINER.join(Iterables.transform(strValues,
                                                               new Function<String, String>() {
                                                                   @Override
                                                                   public String apply(String input) {
                                                                       return "'" + input.replaceAll("'", "''") + "'";
                                                                   }
                                                               })));

List<ResultObject> resultObjects =
        getSimpleJdbcTemplate().query(sql, resultObjectRowMapper());
```

But it seems odd I have to build my own IN clause, surround the strings with single quotes, and escape them myself.  There has got to be better way!  Some additional context: I don't expect to be querying for much (few dozen or few hundred rows max) and optimization isn't too much of a concern as long as we don't query the rows one at a time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread on springsource](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-51820.html), the following should work:

```
String sql = "SELECT col1, col2, col3 "
       + "FROM my_awesome_table "
       + "WHERE strValue IN (:items)";

getSimpleJdbcTemplate().query(
    sql
,   Collections.singletonMap("items", strValues)
,   resultObjectRowMapper()
);
```

Comment: This worked great (although had to switch the row mapper to be second arg) thanks!

Comment: One notice: SimpleJdbTemplate is deprecated since Spring 3.1. The JdbcTemplate and NamedParameterJdbcTemplate now provide all the functionality of the SimpleJdbcTemplate. For IN clause you must take NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, even without JdbcTemplate, you should use prepared statements, and thus let the JDBC driver escape the quotes for you. The SQL query would be something like

```
select ... where strValue in (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

and you would bind each parameter using `PreparedStatement.setParameter()`, without any need to escape anything.

With [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html), it's even easier, because Spring allows using a single parameter for the whole collection of Strings. Its usage is explained in the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#jdbc-NamedParameterJdbcTemplate):

```
String sql = "select ... from ... where strValue in :listOfValues";
Map namedParameters = Collections.singletonMap("listOfValues", strValues);
...
```

Comment: Yes!  I knew I was doing something terribly wrong but was having whatever the writers block equivalent for programmers is!  Thanks!